Изменить свойства существующего ярлыка через powershell
Как изменить свойства существующего ярлыка, а именно добавить --args --enable-plugins с помощью powerShell скрипта и можно ли данный скрипт вызвать при запуске инсталлятора wix?

Изменить свойство ярлыка можно следующим образом:
function Set-Shortcut {
  param(
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
  $LinkPath,
  $Hotkey,
  $IconLocation,
  $Arguments,
  $TargetPath
  )
  begin {
    $shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
  }
  
  process {
    $link = $shell.CreateShortcut($LinkPath)

    $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.GetEnumerator() |
      Where-Object { $_.key -ne 'LinkPath' } |
      ForEach-Object { $link.$($_.key) = $_.value }
    $link.Save()
  }
}
Set-Shortcut <путь к ярлыку> -Arguments  '--args --enable-plugins'

взято отсюда
А про wix не подскажу - не знаю.

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
